# How to convert .xlsx to .txt?

Tags: script, python, perl

I want to know if there is a Linux tool or a script available to convert `.xlsx` file to `.txt`.

Comment: Not a very clear question to be honest. What do you have in the file? Just data? Or are there charts, macros, etc. as well?

Comment: There are lots of them available online. xlsx is a proprietary (and a relatively new) format so the effectiveness of open source tools will be limited I think. Try http://tinyurl.com/2vbb7m5

Comment: something like http://wizard.ae.krakow.pl/~jb/xls2txt/ , but for xlsx

Answer (score 10):

The [ssconvert](http://projects.gnome.org/gnumeric/doc/sect-files-ssconvert.shtml) tool that comes with [Gnumeric](http://projects.gnome.org/gnumeric/) can convert xlsx files to text:

```
ssconvert Book1.xlsx file.csv
```

Comment: and it's flexible and fast ! #recommended

Answer (score 9):

Another way is rename it as .zip and unzip it as all the .***x files are just zipped folders containing xml.  Inside you will find a folder "xl" with a subfolder "worksheets", inside is an xml file for each worksheet.  The format of them is pretty simple and should be easy to parse with any of the xml packages.

Comment: +1 interesting. I'm looking at these XML files now, and at least in this case it is more complicated than you imply -- sheet1.xml doesn't have any actual text in, but seems to refer to another XML file called sharedStrings.xml, which is where the "content" of the file is stored.

Answer (score 4):

If it's just textual/numerical data (which I have to assume it is, otherwise a text file would be a bit ambitious), then you could try [xlsx2csv](http://kirk.webfinish.com/2009/12/xlsx2csv/) to generate CSV files from your spreadsheets.

I can't vouch for its effectiveness, but it's worth a try.

Answer (score 3):

I do not know about a tool in linux, but you can use [Google Docs](http://docs.google.com).

You upload the spreadsheet there and you can then export it as txt.

Answer (score 2):

Not a shell script, (unlike the script mentioned in Andy's post from Oct 20 '10 at 8:44),  but a python script:

with the same name, [xlsx2csv](https://github.com/dilshod/xlsx2csv)

This exports date values as floats though:

2012/07/01 => 41091,

"2012/07/01 01:00:00" => 41091.0416666667

```
xlsx2csv.py --help 
Usage: xlsx2csv.py [options] infile [outfile]

Options:
  --version             show program's version number and exit


     -h, --help            show this help message and exit
      -s SHEETID, --sheet=SHEETID
                            sheet no to convert (0 for all sheets)
      -d DELIMITER, --delimiter=DELIMITER
                            delimiter - csv columns delimiter, 'tab' or 'x09' for
                            tab (comma is default)
      -p SHEETDELIMITER, --sheetdelimiter=SHEETDELIMITER
                            sheets delimiter used to separate sheets, pass '' if
                            you don't want delimiters (default '--------')
      -f DATEFORMAT, --dateformat=DATEFORMAT
                            override date/time format (ex. %Y/%m/%d)
      -i, --ignoreempty     skip empty lines
      -r, --recursive       convert recursively
```

Answer (score 2):

I used the command below to convert all my xlsx files in the current directory (must have Libre Office installed):

```
for i   in *.xlsx; do  libreoffice --headless --convert-to csv "$i" ; done
```

Libreoffice is really good to read Excel and write CSVs. See if your executable isn't called `scalc`.

Comment: In my version of LibreOffice (on Mac) it's `scalc` instead of `libreoffice`.

Comment: better than xlsx2csv

Answer (score 1):

Not command line, but OpenOffice can read .xslx files and save as csv.  Its probably already on your Linux machine.